# How to create a complex compound index for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I need to run the following query on a MongoDB database often.

```
In a collection of account balance logs with fields
- accountAddress
- day
- hour
- minute
- balance
find the most recent balance log of a specific address.
```

I was told that the performance of this query can be drastically improved using compound indexes in MongoDB. How can this index be created, ideally using MongoDB Compass?

Comment: The mechanics of what buttons to push to create the index in a tool like Compass are easy to find. First result of a search is for the [Manage Indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/indexes/) documentation page for Compass which seems to address your concern as stated. But there's more to your question which can't be answered - we would need further details about the exact query that you intend to run in order to determine what index definition would actually be most beneficial. Just because you create an index, or multiple indexes, doesn't mean they will help a query